# Remove axes in matplotlib subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a pandas dataframe with 4 columns and a date range as the index. After showing the trend lines on four subplots using this code, I realized I don't want the y axis ticks or labels, but I can't find any advice on removing them from the subplots; everything I try only works on the bottom plot.

```
plot4 = CZBCdf2.plot(subplots=True,figsize=(10,4),sharex=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

The typical way of removing axis in matplotlib is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis('off')
```

This, however, is a general instruction in matplotlib. To set the axis to invisible you can do (using a subplot):

```
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) # same for y axis.
```

You seem to be calling the plot from other source. If this instructions don't do the stuff you need provide more of your code to see what might be the procedure to achieve that.

Comment: this does not work when one uses plot function of pandas with subplot=True as it is the case in this question.

Answer (score 4):

A complete solution to remove anything around the plot

```
figure, axis = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[10,3])
axis.plot(...)
axis.xaxis.set_visible(False)
axis.yaxis.set_visible(False)
for spine in ['top', 'right', 'left', 'bottom']:
   axis.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
figure.savefig('demo.png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent="True", pad_inches=0,  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `yticks=[]`

So, in your example:

```
plot4 = CZBCdf2.plot(subplots=True,figsize=(10,4),sharex=True, yticks=[])
```